# What is a specific observation of a probability parameter estimate? Programmer trying to understand statistics

Tags: binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem, parameter-estimation

I am trying to understand the following statement about a collection of independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables.

> We have $\theta$ as the probability of success of the Bernoulli random
> variable. Generally we can think of a specific observation of the
> probability parameter estimate as a random variable,  $\hat{\theta}$.
> that can be estimated as $\hat{\theta} =\bar{Y} =
> > \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ where $Y_i$ are Bernoulli random
> variables. We can see that our parameter estimate(random variable) is
> equal to the sample mean of the $Y_i$ follows a normal distribution
> $\mathcal{N}(\theta,\theta(1-\theta)/n)$ and so we can use the
> z-statistic for the confidence intervals for the Bernoulli parameter
> $\theta$.

I am from a programming background and new to statistics. I think I understand that in statistics, parameters refer to populations, unlike in programming where parameters are passed as inputs to a function.

I am having trouble processing several things about the above statement.

1. What is meant by a specific observation of the probability parameter estimate.
   How does one observe an estimate? Would "observing" mean "calculating" here?
2. What name do I use to describe the inputs to this normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\theta,\theta(1-\theta)/n)$ ?

As a programmer I would call them parameters. But I am understanding that is wrong in statistics.

3. I am understanding that the variance of a binomial distribution is given by $np(1-p)$ and I know that with CLT we divide the variance by n. However shouldn't that mean that the input to the normal distribution would be  just $\theta(1-\theta)$ since the $n$ would cancel out?
4. Is the $p$ in my understanding of a binomial probability the same as $\theta$ here?

I am understanding that

- $\hat{\theta}$ means "a point estimate of $\theta$".
- $\bar{Y}$ means "The mean of Y"

[Update]

From River's answer I see that in $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ the fraction is causing a scaling, where as to me it looks like it is causing an ordinary maths multiplication. Is there any special notation to differentiate scaling and/or translations from ordinary multiplication and addition operations?

Comment: The $Y_i$ should not just be Bernoulli, but independent and identically distributed, otherwise this is false.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question to show that they are.

Comment: "the fraction is causing a scaling, where as to me it looks like it is causing an ordinary maths multiplication" Why do you imagine that those are mutually exclusive, or even different? Multiplying the random variable by a number scales the distribution. Adding a number to the random variable translates the distribution.

Comment: So here scaling just means multiplying each $y_i$ ?

Comment: Yes. For an analogy, think about a polynomial $y = p(x)$ and its graph. Multiplying the outputs by a constant $y = ap(x)$, where $a > 0$, scales the graph vertically by a factor of $a$. Adding a constant to the outputs, $y = p(x) + b$, translates the graph up or down by $p$. Similarly, multiplying a random variable by a number, or adding a number to it, is going to scale its density function, or shift its density function left or right. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What is meant by a specific observation of the probability parameter estimate. How does one observe an estimate? Would "observing" mean "calculating" here?

Let's take a specific example. Suppose a pollster wants to figure out the true percentage $\theta$ or $p$ of voters in their country who approve of Polly Politician. They pick out a series of random people, Voter 1, Voter 2, Voter 3, ..., Voter $n$ and ask them "Do you approve of Polly? (Y/N)". The responses they get are the random variables $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, ..., Y_n$, where the value of $Y_i = 0$ if the voter does not approve, and $Y_i = 1$ if the voter does approve. If the sample is a) small enough compared to the entire population, and b) randomly enough selected from the population, then we may assume that $Y_i$ are approximately i.i.d. Bernoulli with $P(Y_i = 1) = \theta$.

A "specific observation" would be the actual observed sequence of responses (or corresponding $0$'s and $1$'s) gotten from Voters 1 through $n$ here when the pollster asked  their opinion. We can loosely speak of any statistic based on/calculated from these observations, such as the sample mean $\hat{\theta}$ which we are using to estimate the true population parameter $\theta$, as also having been "observed" when the pollster performed their experiment.

> 2. What name do I use to describe the inputs to this normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\theta,\theta(1-\theta)/n)$?

You would still call $\theta$ and $\theta(1 - \theta)/n$ "parameters" of the distribution, statistically.

> 3. I am understanding that the variance of a binomial distribution is given by $np(1−p)$ and I know that with CLT we divide the variance by $n$. However shouldn't that mean that the input to the normal distribution would be just $θ(1−θ)$ since the $n$ would cancel out?

$n\hat{\theta} = Y_1 + ... + Y_n$ is binomial with mean $n\theta$ and variance $n\theta(1-\theta)$, which means it's approximated by a normal $X_n$ with mean $n \theta$ and variance $n \theta(1-\theta)$:

$$n\hat{\theta} \approx X_n, \text{ where } X_n \sim \mathcal{N} (n\theta, n\theta(1-\theta)).$$

Dividing by $n$ to get the sample mean $\hat{\theta}$ gives us the approximation

$$\hat{\theta} \approx \frac{1}{n} X_n,$$

and $\frac{1}{n} X_n$ will still be normal, and its mean has been divided by $n$, but its variance has been divided by $n^2$ (reason: variance is average squared distance from the mean; if we divide all the distances by $n$, we divide the squared distances by $n^2$). So our normal approximation $\frac{1}{n} X_n$ to $\hat{\theta}$ has distribution $\frac{1}{n} X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta,\theta(1-\theta)/n)$.

> Is the $p$ in my understanding of a binomial probability the same as $θ$ here?

Yep, different notation for the same thing.

Comment: I am having trouble with the concept of dividing a distribution by a number

Comment: @kirsten You’re dividing the random variable $X_n$ by a number $n$, which creates a new random variable $\frac{1}{n} X_n$. This random variable has a different distribution than $X_n$. If I change my random variable, I change my distribution too, right?

Comment: Thanks, is scaling the correct term here? As in we are scaling by 1/n? And we need to understand the original distribution in order to know the effect on the created distribution?

Comment: @KirstenGreed We can say something even more general than scaling: it's a standard fact that any scaling and/or translation of a normally distributed random variable produces another normally distributed random variable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Operations_on_normal_deviates "If $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then for any real numbers $a$ and $b$, the random variable $Y = aX + b$ is also normally distributed, with mean $a \mu + b$ and standard deviation $|a| \sigma$."

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. I updated the question in the light of it.

Answer (score 2):

1. I think that "specific observation" isn't a very good term here. Usually observation (of random variable) means a concrete value of this variable we got from experiment.
2. They are named parameters, too (more specifically - mean and variance). Generally, in mathematics (including statistics), parameter is something we use to define a concrete object from some set. For example, linear function can be defined by two parameters: $f(x) = ax + b$. When you choose specific values, say $a = 2$ and $b = 3$, you get concrete linear function $f(x) = 2x + 3$. Sometimes in such cases we say "function $f$ is parameterized by $a$ and $b$".
3. When we divide variable by $n$, it's variance is divided by $n^2$. CLT says that if we divide our binomial distribution by $\sqrt{n}$, we get approximately normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\sqrt{n}\theta, \theta (1 - \theta))$. But we divide it by $n$, not by $\sqrt{n}$ - so we divide our approximately normal distribution by $\sqrt{n}$ once more, and get approximately $\mathcal{N}\left(\theta, \frac{\theta (1 - \theta)}{n}\right)$.
4. Yes, it is.